# Phase change rate of human speech

Tags: phase, speech, hilbert-transform, analytic-signal

I have a .wav file of human speech, sampled at 48kHz, with useful signal up to 5kHz, and almost no noise. If I do Hilbert transform in MatLab, I get the Analytic signal:

$$ s_\mathrm{a}[n] = s_\mathrm{real}[n] + j \cdot s_\mathrm{hi}[n], $$

where $s_\mathrm{hi}[n]$ is a Hilbert transformation of $s_\mathrm{real}[n]$ from the .wav file. Now for each sample I can calculate the phase:

$$ \phi[n] = \operatorname{Arctan}\left( \frac{s_\mathrm{hi}[n]}{s_\mathrm{real}[n]} \right) $$

and take time derivative from it. That will be the speed of phase changing. I don't want to call it "instantaneous frequency", that's too controversial.

Is any smarter way of doing this in MatLab? Probably this:

```
Fs/(2*pi)*diff(unwrap(angle(hilbert(s_real))));
```

I did this in Adobe Audition plugin, in Delphi. Way too many spikes, every time when the envelope $\sqrt{s_\mathrm{real}^2[n] + s_\mathrm{hi}^2[n]} $ was around zero.

Comment: You calculate something and then you are not happy with the results. In order to help you we need to know what you actually want to do and why you did expect that the calculation to come up with something meaningful. In general, the "thing" you calculate is useful for narrow band signals, but for broad band signals like speech, it has little usable information or properties. Why do you think otherwise ?

Comment: there is no controversy in calling the rate of change of phase of a sinusoid (w.r.t. time), the *"instantaneous frequency"*.  that is what it is.  but if the input is not a simple sinusoid, but an added collection of sinusoids, there are **many** instantaneous frequencies, not just one.  perhaps that is what you are finding to be controversial?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. If the "thing" works well for SSB radio signal, LSB or USB (I'm ham radio operator), because it is narrow band (3kHz on 3.5MHz) - why it wouldn't work when you transfer radio signal to the baseband? It should, I just calculated it wrong.

Comment: Before asking the question, I did some homework: term "instantaneous frequency" has quite a history of even academic discussions. I try to stay low, just  to find the right algorithm to get the phase change rate of human speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will not address the question whether or not it is meaningful to compute the instantaneous frequency of a speech signal. Instead I will show you a better method for computing the instantaneous frequency from a given analytic signal. This method avoids the phase unwrapping problem by directly computing the instantaneous frequency from the real and imaginary parts of the (discrete-time) analytic signal

$$s[n]=s_R[n]+js_I[n]\tag{1}$$

where

$$ s_I[n] = \mathscr{H} \big\{ s_R[n] \big\} $$

with $\mathscr{H}\{\cdot\}$ denoting the (discrete) Hilbert transform.

First, note that the formula for computing the phase given in your question only works if the real part of the analytic signal is greater than zero. In general you have to use the [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function implemented in most programming languages. In Matlab you can of course use `angle`, as shown in your example code.

Second, the phase becomes irrelevant and undefined if the magnitude of the respective complex number is (close to) zero. So it's pointless trying to compute the phase angle of a complex number with a negligible magnitude. This is true in general, so it doesn't matter how smart your method for computing the instantaneous frequency is.

Let's define the instantaneous frequency of a discrete-time analytic signal as the forward difference

$$f[n]=\frac{\phi[n+1]-\phi[n]}{2\pi T}\tag{2}$$

where $\phi[n]$ is the phase angle of the analytic signal $s[n]$, and $T$ is the sampling period. Note that other definitions such as the backward difference or central difference are also possible and useful.

We will not use $(2)$ directly for computing $f[n]$ because it requires phase unwrapping, which is especially problematic in the presence of noise. With

$$s[n]= \Big|s[n]\Big|e^{j\phi[n]}\tag{3}$$

we get

$$s[n+1]s^*[n]=\Big|s[n+1]\Big|e^{j\phi[n+1]}\cdot \Big|s[n]\Big|e^{-j\phi[n]}=\Big|s[n+1]\Big| \Big|s[n]\Big|e^{j(\phi[n+1]-\phi[n])}\tag{4}$$

(where $^*$ denotes complex conjugation), and, consequently,

$$f[n]=\frac{1}{2\pi T}\arg\Big\{s[n+1]s^*[n]\Big\}\tag{5}$$

The argument should be computed using the `atan2` function. The result of the argument computation is only defined for $s[n]\neq 0$ and $s[n+1]\neq 0$.

Note that using backward or central differences in the definition of the instantaneous frequency would have resulted in the following expressions:

$$\begin{align}f_b[n]&=\frac{1}{2\pi T}\arg\Big\{s[n]s^*[n-1]\Big\}\\f_c[n]&=\frac{1}{4\pi T}\arg\Big\{s[n+1]s^*[n-1]\Big\}=\frac12\big(f[n]+f_b[n]\big)\end{align}$$

Expressing Eq. $(5)$ in terms of the real and imaginary parts of the analytic signal gives:

$\begin{align}
f[n] &=\frac{1}{2\pi T}\arg\Big\{\big(s_R[n+1]+js_I[n+1]\big)\big(s_R[n]-js_I[n]\big) \Big\}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi T}\arg\Big\{s_R[n]s_R[n+1]+s_I[n]s_I[n+1]+j\big(s_R[n]s_I[n+1]-s_R[n+1]s_I[n]\big)\Big\}\\
\end{align}\tag{6}$

More details about instantaneous frequency (and instantaneous bandwidth) can be found in the paper ["The calculation of instantaneous frequency and instantaneous bandwidth"](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/geophysics/article-abstract/57/11/1520/72668/the-calculation-of-instantaneous-frequency-and?redirectedFrom=fulltext) by A.E. Barnes.

Also take a look at [this related answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18979/4298).

Comment: looks like Matt did it for me (thanks, saves me effort).

Comment: Matt, the last equation (7) can be expressed with an $\arctan(\cdot)$ in it as long as we know the change in angle is no more than 90 degrees.

Comment: the last makes use of $$ \operatorname{Arg}(x + iy) = \operatorname{atan2}(y,\, x) =
\begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) &\text{if } x > 0, \\
\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) &\text{if } y > 0, \\
-\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) &\text{if } y < 0, \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \pm \pi &\text{if } x < 0, \\
\text{undefined} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y = 0
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Thanks Robert for correcting a mistake and making some useful changes. I just removed your final `arctan` formula, because I think it was wrong. In general, the real and imaginary parts can have both signs, so there simply is no single `arctan` formula that works in all cases.

Comment: if $s[n]$ an analytic signal, then $S(e^{j\omega})=0$ for $-\pi< \omega < 0$.  then how do any components of it have negative frequency?

Comment: also, this is just kinda an OCD anal question. but might it be better shown as a sorta *causal* process (i know the Hilbert transform is not causal, you gotta delay it a bunch), as: $$f[n]=\frac{\phi[n]-\phi[n-1]}{2\pi T}$$ ?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: An analytic signal has no negative frequencies, agreed. I'm not sure though if its *instantaneous* frequency can't be negative. And apart from that, even if we assume that $\phi[n+1]-\phi[n]\ge 0$, we still have two cases for the `arctan` formula depending on whether the difference is less or greater than $\pi/2$.

Comment: the second case of that atan2 formula deals with any difference between 0 and $+\pi$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: And the definition of $f[n]$ is really just a matter of taste, none of the two is better I think. I've used the one used in the paper I referred to.

Comment: OK, I'll check that, I'm referring to the more common `atan2` cases as shown [here](https://www.medcalc.org/manual/atan2_function.php).

Comment: it's fine.  both $s_R[n]$ and $s_I[n]$ have to be delayed by (in my experience) at least 16 samples anyway.

Comment: the above form has 4 overlapping half-planes.  so, no matter what the real and imag are, you have two expressions that should get you the same answer.

Comment: @K-man: With "undefined" I mean that if the envelope is zero, you can assign any arbitrary value to the phase, it doesn't matter (cf. Eq. (3) in my answer). You simply cannot compute the phase of a complex number with magnitude zero. In practice you should define a threshold for the envelope, and for signals lower than that threshold you don't compute the phase (or instantaneous frequency), or simply assign it some value (e.g., zero).

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson: "have to be delayed by (in my experience) at least 16 samples anyway" - why delayed by 16 samples? Some other reasons, not related with this instant frequency calculations?

Comment: because, to compute the Hilbert transform, in **real time**, and to do a decent job of it with an FIR, i think you will need at least a 33-tap, odd-symmetry, linear-phase FIR.  the delay of that FIR will be (33-1)/2 samples.  so if your quadrature (Hilbert) signal $s_I[n]$ is delayed by 16 samples, so must also your in-phase signal $s_R[n]$ be delayed by the same amount for your comparing and combining the two to work correctly.  (and your answer will be delayed by the same 16 samples, but at least it will be *"correct"*.)

Comment: Would IIR do the Hilbert transform, for example following Theodor A. Prosch,  "A Minimalist Approximation of the Hilbert Transform", Sept/Oct 2012 QEX,  pp
25-31. I'm testing it in Adobe Audition plugin. It splits real signal into I & Q pair, which allows to compute instantaneous frequency, according to your math above. Funny thing is: when envelope goes to zero, but still over any reasonable threshold, frequency goes up or down, as on my picture on the bottom (which I computed differently: shifting phase in Audition, unwrapping phase, before learning anything in this discussion).

Comment: you can try to do this method from Prosch, but i am not familiar enough to help.  i understand some designs with a pair of IIR all-pass filters (APF) that had phase **differing** by about 90° between the APFs.  one APF output is your *in-phase* component and the other APF outputs your *quadrature* component.  but i dunno exactly how to design those two IIR APFs.  but i **do** know how to use MATLAB `firpm()` or `firls()` to design an FIR Hilbert filter that is phase linear (a constant delay along with the 90° shift).

Answer (score 1):

instead of calculating angle (from the real and imaginary parts), unwrapping the wrapped angle, and computing a difference, the better way is to compute the difference from the real and imaginary parts directly.

this (computing instantaneous frequency from the hilbert transform) is very similar to the same phase unwrapping problem in computing group delay (from the phase response of an LTI filter). [Check out here how to do that.  No unwrapping is needed.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10503/converting-from-a-phase-response-to-a-group-delay-response-and-vice-versa/44103#44103)

Comment: i'll come back here and make this answer more explicit, or find a post that had already done that.  but i will do that later.

Comment: Hilmar asked me what I don't like in my calculations of the "thing". Spikes, as I said, which happen at zero envelope. Matt: can you elaborate more on this please: "the phase becomes irrelevant and undefined if the magnitude of the respective complex number is (close to) zero. So it's pointless trying to compute the phase angle of a complex number with a negligible magnitude." Why undefined? It probably just doesn't make any physical sense. In radio amplifiers the "noise gate" is implemented, in math I guess we should make it zero.

Comment: I tried not to deal with the phase angle directly, but used time derivative of arctan, like Barnes Equation (3). Result was the same, with spikes exceeding speech bandwidth. I will try to use this approach above. Still, I think signal around zero should be handled (cut off) manually. Not the elegant solution...

Comment: @K-man: The phase of a complex number is undefined if its magnitude is zero. Look at Eq. (3) in my answer, if $|s[n]|=0$ you can assign any value to $\phi[n]$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Phase Change Rate example]

I was not correct, suggesting to zeroize the rate. What I meant is on the diagram, where the original speech signal is shown, its Hilbert transform, envelope, wrapped phase, its change rate and the corresponding LSB signal.

Note obvious facts: peaks and valleys of Hilbert signal correspond to the max min change rate of original signal, and vice versa. Envelope of analytic signal is the same as the SSB envelope. Phase is decreasing, its change rate is negative, because it's Lower Side Band. Those spikes, which I was talking about, are happening at the moments when the envelope is close to zero. They even go to positive frequency area, which doesn't make sense at all. I suggest to cut them off, assigning some average red values from the adjacent samples. Same as Matt is saying that any value can be assigned at those moments.

It's easy to do in Paint, but I am looking for some math algorithm to do this automatically. That math above still requires manual exclusion of close-to-zero signals.

PS please ignore the vertical artefacts, that's calculation defect. The phase change rate is reasonably smooth.

Comment: Why don't you just threshold the envelope, and assign the previous valid phase rate change value to the current one if the envelope is smaller than the threshold?

Comment: @Matt: I will do threshold. Interestingly enough, those spikes are pretty wide, when they start - envelope is not zero yet. Initially I thought that it's not enough precision around zero, when making all this math. So I used even 768kHz sampling rate.