# Group delay of non differentiable unwrapped phase

Tags: frequency, phase, group-delay

As we know group delay as a function of frequency, computed as differentiation of  unwrapped phase, but what happen  at those frequencies where unwrapped phase is non differentiable?how to calculate delay at that particular frequency?

Comment: [Here is a general way to calculate group delay from the phase delay.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10503/converting-from-a-phase-response-to-a-group-delay-response-and-vice-versa/44103#44103)  But since it's discrete frequency data (the result of an FFT), there is no differentiation.  Just approximating it with the finite difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are phase discontinuities after all $2\pi$-jumps have been removed, then these discontinuities are usually caused by zeros of the frequency response. The phase jumps by $\pi$ at these frequencies, and the group delay doesn't exist, or, if one prefers, is non-finite. Note that the group delay is meaningless anyway at frequencies where the frequency response is zero.